# Set-builder notation and predicate logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

I always had trouble translating set-builder notation to predicate logic. When dealing with the most basic examples, all seems pretty straightfoward to me. However, some texts use translations that are not in harmony with my knowledge. So, I'll first cover the cases (I suppose) I understand:

1. $S = \{ x : P(x)\}$ is equivalent to $\forall x[x \in S \leftrightarrow P(x)] $
2. $S = \{ x \in A\}$ is equivalent to $\forall x[x \in S \leftrightarrow x \in A] $
3. $S = \{ x \in A : P(x)\}$ is equivalent to $\forall x[x \in S \leftrightarrow x \in A \space\land P(x)]$

And here I present the cases I'm having a hard time with:

4. [Image of a mapping] $S = \{ y \in Y : \exists x \in A : y = f(x)\}$. Is it equivalent to $\forall x[x \in S \leftrightarrow \forall y[y \in Y \rightarrow \exists x [x \in A \space\land y = f(x)]]$?
5. [taken from the Wikipedia article about Cantor's theorem] $S = \{ x \in A : x \notin f(x)\}$. The article says this is equivalent to $\forall x \in A (x \in S \leftrightarrow x \notin f(x))$. How? For me, it would be: $\forall x[x \in S \leftrightarrow x \in A \space \land x \notin f(x)]$.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written in 3), to write $S = \{ x \in A : P(x) \}$ means that the set $S$ is the subset of $A$ "made of" the elements of $A$ that satisfy condition $P(x)$.

In the same way for 4), the set $S$ is the subset of $Y$ that satisfies the condition to the right of "$:$".

This means: $y \in S \leftrightarrow (y \in Y \land ∃x \in A(y=f(x)))$.

This amounts to saying that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $Y$ and $S$ is the subset of $Y$ made of "images" of elements of $A$, and this is what we expect as "image".

---

The same for 5): $S = \{ x∈A : x∉f(x) \}$.

The set $S$ is made of the elements $x$ of $A$ such that $x \notin f(x)$, i.e.

> $x \in S \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \notin f(x))$.

An this in turn implies [in fact, it is equivalent to]:

> > $x \in A \to (x \in S \leftrightarrow x \notin f(x))$.

Comment: Thank you for very precise answer, Mr Allegranza. I still have some questions: 1) the first is a simple formality: you mean $x \in S \leftrightarrow (y \in Y \land \exists x \in A (y = f(x)))$? 2) still about number 4: if the definition of surjectivity is $\forall y \in Y \exists x \in X y=f(x)$, why $y \in Y$ in your predicate conversion is not universally quantified? 3) about number 5: this means that $x \in S \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \notin f(x))$ is not equivalent to $x \in A \rightarrow (x \in S \leftrightarrow x \notin f(x))$, rather that the first implies the second, right?

Comment: @TylerD007 - yes, a typo; I'll correct it. And yes, the two formulas are universally quantified.

Comment: Hence, according to your reasoning, given that $\forall y [y \in S \leftrightarrow (y \in Y \land \exists x \in A (y = f(x)))]$ is the definition of image of a function and $\forall y \in Y \exists x \in X (y=f(x))$ is the defitinion of surjectivity, is it correct to say that the first implies the second?

Comment: @TylerD007 - Yes; a [Surjective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) is a function such that every element of the *codomain* is "mapped to" some element of the domain. $Y$ is the *codomain* and $S$ is the *range* or *image*. $S \subseteq Y$ and obviouslu every element of the *image* is "mapped to" by something.

Comment: And we can prove the equivalence, because we can use $x \in S \to x \in A$.